# AbortController not terminating fetch request

Tags: javascript, node.js, timeout, es6-promise, fetch-api

I'm attempting to create a helper function to automatically timeout `fetch` requests after 2000 ms. The following code does not abort the fetch request, and instead prints the request as normal after 4000 ms. The code appears to be working in browser but not in node.

```js
require('isomorphic-fetch');
const AbortController = require('abort-controller');

const fetchTimeout = async url => {
  const controller = new AbortController();

  setTimeout(() => {
    controller.abort();
  }, 2000);

  return fetch(url, { signal: controller.signal })
    .then(response => {
      return response;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      throw new Error(error.message);
    });
};

const getStock = async () => {
  return await fetchTimeout('https://httpbin.org/delay/4').then(data =>
    data.json()
  );
};

( async () => 
console.log(await getStock())
)();
```

Comment: Now that you’ve inserted `{ signal: controller.signal }` after your edit, the code works just fine.

Comment: @SebastianSimon just tested and it seems to be working fine in browser, but not in node.js with the packages in my latest edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by using the node-fetch library instead of isomorphic-fetch with no other implementation issues. I've logged a ticket [here](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch/issues/185), hope this can help someone else experiencing this frusturating issue.

Comment: Looks like AbortController support is coming to isomorphic-fetch "soon"